# how can i use power query to turn api json response into table?

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing

so due to the api key giving me issues i have to download json formatted data  using vba and not power query. the api response, i would like to parse into a table or use power query to turn into a table.

The code i tried is not working. it gives me.... Runtime error 10001 "Expecting '""' or '''"....  i'm sure it has something to do with "JSONConverter" code i downloaded and tried to use.this is the website that helped me figure out the code i wrote http://excelerator.solutions/2017/08/16/import-json-to-excel-using-vba/ .i'm open to scraping it if someone has a better way of doing it. lastly this is a decently big amount of data to put into one cell,do you recommend using a cell or some other way to hold data that will be parced?

this is a sample of the json file

```
Dim jsonText As String
Dim jsonObject As Object, item As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("sheet20")

'ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = res
jsonText = ws.Cells(1, 1)

Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

i = 3

ws.Cells(2, 1) = "WorkOrderNumber"
'ws.Cells(2, 2) = "Customer Name"
'ws.Cells(2, 3) = "Location Name"
'ws.Cells(2, 4) = "IsInvoiced"
'ws.Cells(2, 5) = "Team"
'ws.Cells(2, 6) = "WorkOrderDate"
'ws.Cells(2, 7) = "DateFinished"
'ws.Cells(2, 8) = "ScheduledTime"
'ws.Cells(2, 9) = "EstimatedDuration"
'ws.Cells(2, 10) = "Notes"
'ws.Cells(2, 11) = "PrivateNotes"
'ws.Cells(2, 1) = "SalesRepresentative"
'ws.Cells(2, 2) = "Description"
'ws.Cells(2, 3) = "Status"
'ws.Cells(2, 4) = "IsInvoiced"
'ws.Cells(2, 5) = "Team"
'ws.Cells(2, 6) = "WorkOrderDate"
'ws.Cells(2, 7) = "DateFinished"
'ws.Cells(2, 8) = "ScheduledTime"
'ws.Cells(2, 9) = "EstimatedDuration"
'ws.Cells(2, 10) = "Notes"
'ws.Cells(2, 11) = "PrivateNotes"
'ws.Cells(2, 12) = "CreatedBy"
'ws.Cells(2, 13) = "CreatedOn"
'ws.Cells(2, 14) = "UpdatedOn"
'ws.Cells(2, 15) = "UpdatedBy"
'ws.Cells(2, 16) = "Version"

For Each item In jsonObject("Data")
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = item("WorkOrderNumber")
    'ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("Customer")("Name")
    'ws.Cells(i, 3) = item("Location")("Name")
    'ws.Cells(i, 4) = item("Location")("Name")
    'ws.Cells(i, 5) = item("Location")("Name")
    'ws.Cells(i, 6) = item("WorkOrderDate")
    'ws.Cells(i, 7) = item("DateFinished")
    'ws.Cells(i, 8) = item("ScheduledTime")
    'ws.Cells(i, 9) = item("EstimatedDuration")
    'ws.Cells(i, 10) = item("Notes")
    'ws.Cells(i, 11) = item("PrivateNotes")
    'ws.Cells(i, 1) = item("SalesRepresentative")("Name")
    'ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("Description")
    'ws.Cells(i, 3) = item("Status")
    'ws.Cells(i, 4) = item("IsInvoiced")
    'ws.Cells(i, 5) = item("Team")("Name")
    'ws.Cells(i, 6) = item("WorkOrderDate")
    'ws.Cells(i, 7) = item("DateFinished")
    'ws.Cells(i, 8) = item("ScheduledTime")
    'ws.Cells(i, 9) = item("EstimatedDuration")
    'ws.Cells(i, 10) = item("Notes")
    'ws.Cells(i, 11) = item("PrivateNotes")
    'ws.Cells(i, 12) = item("Metadata")("CreatedBy")
    'ws.Cells(i, 13) = item("Metadata")("CreatedOn")
    'ws.Cells(i, 14) = item("Metadata")("UpdatedOn")
    'ws.Cells(i, 15) = item("Metadata")("UpdatedBy")
    'ws.Cells(i, 16) = item("Metadata")("Version")

Next

    End Sub

'here is an example of the json file i want to turn into 1 table
{
  "TotalCount": 148,
  "Data": [
    {
      "WorkOrderNumber": "PV 298-0-0",
      "Scheduler": {
        "SchedulerId": 19469471,
        "SchedulerNumber": "PV 298-0-0",
        "ScheduleType": "Project"
      },
      "Customer": {
        "Inactive": false,
        "Id": 6985214,
        "Name": "blah"
      },
      "Location": {
        "Id": 7513954,
        "Name": "Primary"
      },
      "GeoCoordinates": null,
      "CoordinatesCaptured": null,
      "Contact": {
        "Id": 7316098,
        "Name": "blah"
      },
      "ThirdPartyBillPayer": null,
      "IsMarketingCampaignSetByLead": false,
      "MarketingCampaign": {
        "Id": 115753,
        "Name": "Web Call In"
      },
      "JobCategory": null,
      "SalesRepresentative": {
        "Id": 242299,
        "Name": "blah"
      },
      "DefaultEquipment": null,
      "Description": "Gutter/Guard Estimate",
      "Status": "Suspended",
      "IsInvoiced": false,
      "Branch": {
        "Id": 145945,
        "Name": "-VA"
      },
      "Team": {
        "Id": 177760,
        "Name": "blah"
      },
      "TeamMembers": [
        {
          "EmployeeId": 242299,
          "UserId": 179578,
          "FirstName": "blah",
          "LastName": "Bblah",
          "Email": "blah.com",
          "Title": null
        }
      ],
      "ConfirmationStatus": "SentEmail",
      "WorkOrderDate": "2017-05-24T00:00:00",
      "DateFinished": null,
      "ScheduledTime": 1097,
      "EstimatedDuration": 25,
      "ArrivalWindow": 60,
      "EarliestArrival": null,
      "LatestDeparture": null,
      "Notes": "Client requests new seamless 5\" white gutters and downspouts to prevent sol erosion around foundation of home. Client has also requested we install One Guard with 20yr money back guarantee. Due to client replacing siding,we've agreed to remove existing gutters and come back to install new gutters on a separate day as close to the siding job beginning and ending as possible.",
      "PrivateNotes": "blah",
      "InvoiceNotes": null,
      "ReminderType": "None",
      "ReminderValue": 0,
      "ReminderMessage": "",
      "WorkOrderLines": [],
      "CustomFields": [
        {
          "Name": "CC Referred By",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E3 Electric:",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W3 Yard Sign Posted",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P2 Materials Checked",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P3 Photos & Diagrams Included",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W8 Referrals given to Customer",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E2 Ladders Needed:",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P4 Priority List",
          "Value": "False"
        },
        {
          "Name": "P Material Box",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E4 Takedown",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W6 Describe Delays",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W7 Final walk around/Payment Taken",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W5 Amount of  Delay Due To Work Obstacles",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W Tools/Materials visually inspected",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E Roof Pitch",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E1 Roof Material ",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC1 Marketing Source Correction",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC4 Estimate Summary Correction",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S Walk Around Done",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S1 All Expectations Set In Writing/Photos",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S2 I Feel Est. Will Close In",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S3 I went for",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E5 Movement Difficulty",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC3 Time Lost ",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S4 Est Rating",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S6 Reason Client Chose our Company",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S5 Solutionist notes",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W1 Called in Rought",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W2 initial walk around completed",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W4 Safety Concerns/Description",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W9 Client Rating",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S7 Follow Up Notes",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC5 Reasons for Area of Improvement",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC2 Est. Scheduling Area of Improvement",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P1 Man Hours",
          "Value": ""
        }
      ],
      "Id": 19469471,
      "Metadata": {
        "CreatedBy": "blah.com",
        "CreatedOn": "2017-07-14T11:34:27",
        "UpdatedOn": "2019-09-19T11:08:36",
        "UpdatedBy": "ServiceBridge",
        "Version": 4
      },
      "ExternalSystemId": null
    },
    {
      "WorkOrderNumber": "WO 370",
      "Scheduler": null,
      "Customer": {
        "Inactive": false,
        "Id": 6997686,
        "Name": "blah"
      },
      "Location": {
        "Id": 7527330,
        "Name": "Primary"
      },
      "GeoCoordinates": null,
      "CoordinatesCaptured": null,
      "Contact": {
        "Id": 7329676,
        "Name": "blah"
      },
      "ThirdPartyBillPayer": null,
      "IsMarketingCampaignSetByLead": false,
      "MarketingCampaign": {
        "Id": 115748,
        "Name": "Home Advisor"
      },
      "JobCategory": null,
      "SalesRepresentative": {
        "Id": 242299,
        "Name": "blah"
      },
      "DefaultEquipment": null,
      "Description": "50' downspout",
      "Status": "Completed",
      "IsInvoiced": true,
      "Branch": {
        "Id": 145945,
        "Name": "VA"
      },
      "Team": {
        "Id": 177761,
        "Name": "VB-Truck 1 (5'\"-6\" Combo)"
      },
      "TeamMembers": [
        {
          "EmployeeId": 242200,
          "UserId": 179580,
          "FirstName": "blah",
          "LastName": "blah",
          "Email": "blah.com",
          "Title": ""
        }
      ],
      "ConfirmationStatus": "None",
      "WorkOrderDate": "2017-06-28T00:00:00",
      "DateFinished": "2017-06-28T21:31:20",
      "ScheduledTime": 1051,
      "EstimatedDuration": 0,
      "ArrivalWindow": 0,
      "EarliestArrival": null,
      "LatestDeparture": null,
      "Notes": "Replace 50' of downspout for client using 11 a elbows",
      "PrivateNotes": null,
      "InvoiceNotes": null,
      "ReminderType": "None",
      "ReminderValue": 0,
      "ReminderMessage": null,
      "WorkOrderLines": [
        {
          "Id": 22952669,
          "ParentId": null,
          "Inventory": {
            "Id": 1688245,
            "SKU": "2X3­-AE­-ALU­-WHT",
            "Name": "2x3\" Aluminum White A Elbow",
            "Type": "Product"
          },
          "Price": 5.0,
          "Quantity": 15.0,
          "Description": "A Elbows are typically used to attach a downspoutto the face of a structure. They are also used on other areas of a downspout enabling it to conform to the contour of a structure.",
          "IsTaxable": false,
          "Tax": null
        },
        {
          "Id": 22952604,
          "ParentId": null,
          "Inventory": {
            "Id": 1688247,
            "SKU": "2X3­-DS­ALU­-WHI",
            "Name": "2x3\" Aluminum White Downspout",
            "Type": "Product"
          },
          "Price": 5.0,
          "Quantity": 50.0,
          "Description": "Downspouts carry rainwater from the gutter to the ground.",
          "IsTaxable": false,
          "Tax": null
        }
      ],
      "CustomFields": [
        {
          "Name": "CC Referred By",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E3 Electric:",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W3 Yard Sign Posted",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P2 Materials Checked",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P3 Photos & Diagrams Included",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W8 Referrals given to Customer",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E2 Ladders Needed:",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P4 Priority List",
          "Value": "False"
        },
        {
          "Name": "P Material Box",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E4 Takedown",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W6 Describe Delays",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W7 Final walk around/Payment Taken",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W5 Amount of  Delay Due To Work Obstacles",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W Tools/Materials visually inspected",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E Roof Pitch",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E1 Roof Material ",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC1 Marketing Source Correction",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC4 Estimate Summary Correction",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S Walk Around Done",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S1 All Expectations Set In Writing/Photos",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S2 I Feel Est. Will Close In",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S3 I went for",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "E5 Movement Difficulty",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC3 Time Lost ",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S4 Est Rating",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S6 Reason Client Chose our Company",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S5 Solutionist notes",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W1 Called in Rought",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W2 initial walk around completed",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W4 Safety Concerns/Description",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "W9 Client Rating",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "S7 Follow Up Notes",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC5 Reasons for Area of Improvement",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "CC2 Est. Scheduling Area of Improvement",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Name": "P1 Man Hours",
          "Value": ""
        }
      ],
      "Id": 19390520,
      "Metadata": {
        "CreatedBy": "ServiceBridge-API",
        "CreatedOn": "2017-06-28T16:20:50",
        "UpdatedOn": "2019-09-19T11:08:36",
        "UpdatedBy": "ServiceBridge",
        "Version": 18
      },
      "ExternalSystemId": null
    },
```

Comment: "its not working" - that doesn't tell us much about your actual problem

Comment: *"this is a sample of the json file"*  No, it isn't.  Although that might be helpful.

Comment: hey guys i'm sorry for the poorly written question, it was the end of the day and this was a last ditch effort. i've  corrected it and would appreciate any help your willing to give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your problem might be.

I modified the last two lines of your JSON example so it would be valid:

[image]

and made some minor changes in your posted code.

I also stored the JSON in a file instead of a worksheet cell.

After doing that, the JSON parsed without error.

**Note that your code does not put the proper column headings, and overwrites itself.  I left that for you to correct.**

```
Option Explicit
Sub doJSON()
    Dim JSON As Object
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream
    Dim strJSON As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Item As Variant

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("D:/Users/Ron/Desktop/New Text Document.json")

strJSON = TS.ReadAll

Set JSON = parsejson(strJSON)

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

i = 3

ws.Cells(2, 1) = "WorkOrderNumber"
ws.Cells(2, 2) = "Customer Name"
ws.Cells(2, 3) = "Location Name"
ws.Cells(2, 4) = "IsInvoiced"
ws.Cells(2, 5) = "Team"
ws.Cells(2, 6) = "WorkOrderDate"
ws.Cells(2, 7) = "DateFinished"
ws.Cells(2, 8) = "ScheduledTime"
ws.Cells(2, 9) = "EstimatedDuration"
ws.Cells(2, 10) = "Notes"
ws.Cells(2, 11) = "PrivateNotes"
ws.Cells(2, 1) = "SalesRepresentative"
ws.Cells(2, 2) = "Description"
ws.Cells(2, 3) = "Status"
ws.Cells(2, 4) = "IsInvoiced"
ws.Cells(2, 5) = "Team"
ws.Cells(2, 6) = "WorkOrderDate"
ws.Cells(2, 7) = "DateFinished"
ws.Cells(2, 8) = "ScheduledTime"
ws.Cells(2, 9) = "EstimatedDuration"
ws.Cells(2, 10) = "Notes"
ws.Cells(2, 11) = "PrivateNotes"
ws.Cells(2, 12) = "CreatedBy"
ws.Cells(2, 13) = "CreatedOn"
ws.Cells(2, 14) = "UpdatedOn"
ws.Cells(2, 15) = "UpdatedBy"
ws.Cells(2, 16) = "Version"

For Each Item In JSON("Data")
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = Item("WorkOrderNumber")
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = Item("Customer")("Name")
    ws.Cells(i, 3) = Item("Location")("Name")
    ws.Cells(i, 4) = Item("Location")("Name")
    ws.Cells(i, 5) = Item("Location")("Name")
    ws.Cells(i, 6) = Item("WorkOrderDate")
    ws.Cells(i, 7) = Item("DateFinished")
    ws.Cells(i, 8) = Item("ScheduledTime")
    ws.Cells(i, 9) = Item("EstimatedDuration")
    ws.Cells(i, 10) = Item("Notes")
    ws.Cells(i, 11) = Item("PrivateNotes")
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = Item("SalesRepresentative")("Name")
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = Item("Description")
    ws.Cells(i, 3) = Item("Status")
    ws.Cells(i, 4) = Item("IsInvoiced")
    ws.Cells(i, 5) = Item("Team")("Name")
    ws.Cells(i, 6) = Item("WorkOrderDate")
    ws.Cells(i, 7) = Item("DateFinished")
    ws.Cells(i, 8) = Item("ScheduledTime")
    ws.Cells(i, 9) = Item("EstimatedDuration")
    ws.Cells(i, 10) = Item("Notes")
    ws.Cells(i, 11) = Item("PrivateNotes")
    ws.Cells(i, 12) = Item("Metadata")("CreatedBy")
    ws.Cells(i, 13) = Item("Metadata")("CreatedOn")
    ws.Cells(i, 14) = Item("Metadata")("UpdatedOn")
    ws.Cells(i, 15) = Item("Metadata")("UpdatedBy")
    ws.Cells(i, 16) = Item("Metadata")("Version")

    i = i + 1

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

The error you see is generally due to an error in the JSON. I suspect either that, or possibly, since you have pasted the JSON into a worksheet cell, perhaps the JSON is longer than the 32,767 character limit of a cell and is, therefore, invalid.

If the JSON is too large to fit into a cell, I suggest you store it in a file and access it using the FileSystemObject (or other method).  If that is not the problem, I would closely check the JSON output for errors.

Comment: thank you Ron i was really stuck but your simple fix of putting it in a seperate txt file did the trick. I'll try to always take my time writing out my questions from now on.